# Merge columns of a specific row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose the data is as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sub_Id': ['SM01', 'SM02', 'SM03'], 'Sub_name': ['English', 'Physics', 'Maths'], 'Marks': ['62', '33', '86']}
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(table)
```

and the output is

```py
  Sub_Id Sub_name Marks
0   SM01  English    62
1   SM02  Physics    33
2   SM03    Maths    86
```

I want to add an extra row which will give output as

```
  Sub_Id Sub_name Marks
0   SM01  English    62
1   SM02  Physics    33
2   SM03    Maths    86
3     Total_marks   181
```

Here the 4th row 1st element `Total_marks` is common to both `Sub_Id` and `Sub_name`

Is this possible through pandas or tabulate or Tableit?

Comment: Are you trying to merge, or merely add the column?

Comment: ```table.loc[table.index[-1]+ 1,:] = ['Total_Marks','',table.Marks.astype(int).sum()]```?

Comment: @PLZHELP Will merge and add produce different outputs? Talking about my problem I think it seems like merging

Comment: Try sam's solution

Comment: Think twice before doing this.  This breaks the abstraction of your DataFrame.  You cannot then again sum the `Marks` column.  If you do any other analysis on this DataFrame will have to keep in mind the row that doesn't belong.

Comment: @sammywemmy this works but doesn't solve my problem. I'm trying to ask that is merging column for a specific row possible in python? Same as that of Excel.

Comment: _Is this possible through pandas or tabulate or Tableit?_ Probably, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].